# Mac OS 10.7 DMG files don't pop up anymore?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, dmg-image

Has anybody noticed that double-clicking on a DMG file no longer raises the mounted image to the front of all windows? It used to be that when you double-clicked a dmg file, it would pop-up but now you have to click Finder and click on the mounted image.

Is this a bug, by design or a setting that I can change?

Update: As per Daniel Beck's suggestion, I created a new account and downloaded the most recent version of Firefox via Safari. It still exhibited the same behavior. However, I noticed that if I double-click thew DMG from within the Downloads folder in Finder, it does pop up. But when I double-click the DMG within Safari (and Firefox also) it does not pop up over all other windows.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Create a second user account on your machine and try there. What happens?

Comment: Also, does it happen with any `.dmg` file or just specific ones? I tried with the *Path Finder* and *Google Chrome* images: They all opened new windows.

Comment: @DanielBeck - How did you open the image? Did you double-click the dmg from Finder or from the browser you downloaded with?

Comment: Finder. You're right: When opened from Safari, Safari doesn't let Finder take over focus. It's only frontmost for a very short time until Safari comes forward again. It suffices to `Cmd-Tab` to Finder though, different from what you describe.

Comment: Similar problem here on 10.8.2 ... Finder does take over focus even when *.dmg file is clicked in the Downloads stack (in Dock)

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the DMG from a full-screen application? When a full screen app is open, nothing else can is supposed to share that space, so the DMG will open in your first space.

AKA:- it's design due to the fact that full-screen applications aren't meant to have popups over them.

Comment: No, it's not being opened from a full-screen application. I'll have to fire up my old Mini to verify the old behavior of dmgs popping up on 10.5 & 10.6